# How to convert from docker-compose to Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project that need to run multiple containers and I want to put it in Elastic Beanstalk.

I already have docker-compose.yml and I want to convert it to Dockerrun.aws.json

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2.0'

services:
   djangoserverdocker:
   build: ./django_server
   command: bash -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate --fake && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80"
volumes:
  - .:/djangoserverdocker
ports:
  - "80:80"

socketserverdocker:
  build:
  context: ./needsocket
ports:
  - '8002:8002'
```

How do I convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate docker-compose.yml to Dockerrun.aws.json for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460512/how-to-translate-docker-compose-yml-to-dockerrun-aws-json-for-django)